# Computational Methods: Explain how to evaluate the following functions accurately for small |x|

Tags: computational-mathematics

Please help me solve this problem. I have a difficult time understanding my professor and need assistance on my homework assignment so I can be prepared when the exam comes. The question is as follows-

Explain how to evaluate the following functions accurately for small $x$

a) $\left[{1\over(1+2x)}\right]+\left[{(1-x)\over(1+x)}\right]$

b) $\sqrt{({1\over x})+x}−\sqrt{({1\over x})-x}$

c) $\operatorname{sinh}(x) = [e^x−e^{-x}]/2$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It would help if you explain what kind of techniques you are covering in your course. Otherwise an answer like: "Go to such and such website and enter the expressions along with desired values of x" would represent a simple/good answer.

Comment: @mega6382:  to put multicharacter items under the square root sign, enclose them in braces.  For example \sqrt {a+b} gives $\sqrt {a+b}$.  It works everywhere, like for numerators and denominators, exponents, subscritpts, etc.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you, for informing me.

Comment: You should avoid subexpressions which are sensitive to small modifications. Modify them, it is better to add two small values then subtract one from the other for example.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to avoid loss of precision when subtracting two nearly equal quantities.  This should be a major theme of your course.  A simple example is computing $1-(1-x)$ for small $x$.  If you compute it as written you will lose many bits of $x$ from the first subtraction.  Try it in your environment for $x=10^{-10}, 10^{-20}, 10^{-30}$.  In my Excel I get zero for $1-(1-x)$ at $x=10^{-10}$.  The fix is to analytically cancel the large term, replacing $1-(1-x)$ with $x$.  You can use Taylor series, because when $x$ is small they converge very rapidly.